# How can i parse variable length strings

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm trying to take multiple lines from a TextBox to use different parts of the text to draw shapes. So far I have this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int BitmapX = 640;
        const int BitmapY = 480;
        //bitmap which will be displayed on picturebox
        Bitmap OutputBitmap = new Bitmap(BitmapX, BitmapY);
        Bitmap CursorBM = new Bitmap(BitmapX, BitmapY);
        Graphics bmG;
        Canvas MyCanvas;
        public bool Checked = false       

  public Form1()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
       bmG = Graphics.FromImage(OutputBitmap);
       MyCanvas = new Canvas(Graphics.FromImage(OutputBitmap));           
  }
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] Lines = ProgramWindow.Text.Split('\n');
            int NumberOfCommands = Lines.Length;          
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfCommands - 1; i++)
                {                                      
                    int VariableValue = 0;
                    string[] Input = Lines[i].ToLower().Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string Command = Input[0];
                    string input1 = Input.Length >= 2 ? Input[0] : " ";
                    string input2 = Input.Length >= 3 ? Input[1] : " ";
                    string input3 = Input.Length >= 4 ? Input[2] : " ";
                    string input4 = Input.Length >= 5 ? Input[3] : " ";
                    Console.WriteLine(Command, input1, input2, input3, input4);                                                          
                    Commands(Command, VariableValue, input1, input2, input3, input4);
                    Refresh();
                }
            }

            void Commands(string Command, int VariableValue, string input1, string input2, string input3, string input4)
            {
                if (input1.Equals("="))
                {
                    int Value = int.Parse(input2);
                    VariableValue = Value;
                    if (input3.Equals("+"))
                    {
                        int AddValue = int.Parse(input4);
                        VariableValue = VariableValue + AddValue;
                    }
                    else if (input3.Equals("*"))
                    {
                        int TimesValue = int.Parse(input4);
                        VariableValue = VariableValue * TimesValue;
                    }
                }
             }
```

The commands I'm trying to type can be multiple formats which is where I'm having a problem the commands can be in the following formats :

> string = int
>
> string = int + int
>
> string int

I'm trying to parse them all as strings so I can parse certain ones as
`int`'s later as needed, but currently I can't get different lengths of text without an 'out of bounds'.

Comment: Can you please provide [mcve]

Comment: Might be overkill, but it seems you could be better off tokenizing the inputs first, using simple lexing rules that could be defined with regular expressions. So given `something = 42 + 27` you would have `Identifier`, `Eq`, `IntegerLiteral`, `AddOp`, and `IntegerLiteral` tokens, and then you can craft parser rules to make them make sense and turn them into a tree representation such that the expression as a whole might be an `AssignmentOperation` where `LHS` is the `IdentifierToken` and the RHS is an `Expression` of type `BinaryOp` with its own LHS and RHS tokens (the ints).

Comment: ..and then you can easily walk that parse tree and interpret/evaluate expressions, and determine that the `something` identifier has a value of 69 in some execution context.

Comment: In other words, make a custom Domain-Specific Language (DSL) parser; you could use ANTLR to generate the lexer and parser from grammar rules.

Comment: In c# we name local variables and method arguments with camelCase